# In Xray jFrog Rest API, How to get details about Indexed repositories

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

How to get list and details of all available and selected (indexed) repositories of the given Artifactory instances in the Xray JFrog using Rest API ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way of achieving that via the REST API. But this is doable from the UI, just browse to the Artifactory configuration and you will be able to see which repositories are configured to be indexed and the completion status.

Answer (score 0):

The method [Get Repos Indexing Configuration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-GetReposIndexingConfiguration) provides the lists of indexed and non-indexded repositories based on a binary manager.